# Replace with single quote to double single quote not working in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

Replace with single quote to double single quote not working properly in PostgreSQL 12, it was working fine in PostgreSQL 11.

**PostgreSQL 12**

Query: `SELECT REPLACE(patient.note,'''',''''''), * FROM patient`

Output Text: `Medicare Secondary Veteran�s Administration`

**PostgreSQL 11**

Query: `SELECT REPLACE(patient.note,'''',''''''), * FROM patient`

Output Text: `Medicare Secondary Veteran’s Administration`

let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: Show us for both: PostgreSQL 11 and PostgreSQL 12 what do you get when you do this: `select note from patient` ? Thanks!

Comment: It is definitely not a single quote. And I doubt if it was ever replaced.

Comment: It seems your migration to Postgres 12 changed the quote (e.g. used a wrong encoding) - and the output for Postgres 11 doesn't match your code. The output shows a  `’` whereas your code uses only "straight" quotes: `'` plus in the output for Postgres 11 (or 12) I would expect **two** single quotes, e.g. `''` - so even the second output does not seem correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your replacement, because the character in question is not an apostrophe `'` (U+0027), but a “right single quotation mark” character `’` (U+2019).

Probably the client encoding for your connection to PostgreSQL v12 isn't set correctly, so that the character is translated to something undesirable. There may also have been a mistake in transferring the character to v12.

To diagnose this, try

```
SELECT note::bytea FROM patient;
```

If this contains `e28099`, the data in your database are fine, and the problem is your client encoding. This assumes that the server encoding of the databases is `UTF8`.